# Creating SWT Forms using Eclipse similar to Visual Studio C#/VB, possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, forms

Please forgive if this question has been asked numerous times.  I recently installed Eclipse Classic v3.6.0 which I need to create a little utility using Java.  In Visual Studio I can create a new form then from the Toolbar I can drag and drop components (Button, TextBox, ListBox, etc) onto the Form.  Is this possible using Eclipse?

I have tried various (see below for a few examples) combination using both Stack Overflow and Google, but nothing that I have seen that discusses this topic.  I have read that there are plug-ins for Eclipse and was thinking there might be a plug-in for this type of behavior? I am not sure if this feature is supported out of the box. Any help is greatly appreciated.

"eclipse form drag drop"
"using eclipse drag and drop form creation"

I have also found the following links that show examples for creating Form using SWT, but these are more of snippets.  These are great if I want to generate the file myself, but I would like the IDE to most of that work (since I am lazy).

SWT Snippets
http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/

SWT GridLayout
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTGridLayout.htm

SWT JFace Eclipse
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CatalogSWT-JFace-Eclipse.htm

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Instantiations SWT Designer](http://www.instantiations.com/windowbuilder/swtdesigner/index.html?id=2) is probably your best bet.

Comment: I agree. If money is an issue, you might try the free Visual Editor - http://www.eclipse.org/vep/. However, the commercial Instatiations product will minimize development costs. The company has a long history of providing quality products for the Eclipse IDE, and fixes defects quickly. They've made my life easier.

Comment: Thanks, zvikico.  I did install the Instantiations SWT Designer.  Coming from the Visual Studio realm, I wish this was built in.  Also, though it will work out of the box it didn't work until the added the following Libraries to the project (after several hours of searching):

org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.0.xxx.jar
org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.6.0.xxx.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.xxx.jar
org.eclipse.jface_3.6.0.xxx.jar
org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.6.0.xxx.jar

It would have been nice the tools pops up a window informing the user this.  Perhaps they have an FAQ, but I didn't see it.